# BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION causing Abort Trap

Tags: c++, exception, boost

I'm trying to use `boost::exception` and have condensed my prototype code down to the example in the [Boost exception tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/exception/doc/tutorial_transporting_data.html) however when running the code with the `BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION` macro I get an abort from the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/exception/all.hpp>

typedef boost::error_info<struct tag_my_info,int> my_info;
struct my_error: virtual boost::exception, virtual std::exception { };

void f()  {
  BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(my_error() << my_info(42));

  // Uncomment the below (and comment the above) for the program to work
  //throw my_error() << my_info(42);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)  {
  try  {
    f();
  }
  catch(my_error& x)  {
    if(int const* mi = boost::get_error_info<my_info>(x))  {
      std::cout << "My info: " << *mi << std::endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Running the code with the `BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION` macro:

```
$ ./a.out 
Abort trap
```

If as the comment says, I swap the code, all is well

```
$ ./a.out 
My info: 42
```

Below is the output from the g++ preprocessor for `f()`

```
void f() {
  ::boost::exception_detail::throw_exception_(my_error() << my_info(42),__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,"main.cpp",14);
}
```

Software versions are:

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin10
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.6 (GCC) 

$ port list boost
boost                          @1.47.0         devel/boost
```

I'm on OSX SL using the tools provided by MacPorts.  I've double checked the g++ search paths and there's only one copy of the boost hpp files and that's the ones that belong to the aforementioned boost package.

I have no idea why the abort trap is being called.  I admit I'm newish to C++ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by using the MacPorts version of g++.  There are plenty of tickets related to exceptions and Abort Traps in the MP system (and plenty of examples on Google).

Using the version of g++ that comes with XCode enabled this problem to go away.